# PHP SQL form with JS action - show result only in individual div instead of all

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I need to echo the result of a dynamically created form post request only in one div.

The original table and scripts are more complex, but I broke it down to the basics for this example.

**Table:**

[image]

**form.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <style>
        body {padding: 30px; font-family: Arial;}
        input {margin: 6px 0;}
        .result {margin-bottom: 30px; color:green;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<?php 

$conn = mysqli_connect('dbserver', 'dbuser', 'dbpw', 'dbname') or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
$conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }  

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY email ASC";  

$rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

//the following part will echo multiple individual forms, depending on the table content. In this case 5.
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) {

    echo '
    '.$row["email"].'

    <form action="marked.php" method="POST" id="marked_form_'.$row["id"].'" class="marked_form">
        <input type="hidden" name="email_to_mark" value="'.$row["email"].'">

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="marked_submit">

    </form>

    <div class="result">
    <!--echo result here-->
    </div>
    ';  
}

?>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".marked_form").submit(function() {
        // Getting the form ID
        var  formID = $(this).attr('id');
        var formDetails = $('#'+formID);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'marked.php',
            data: formDetails.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {  
                // Inserting html into the result div
                $('.result').html(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, text, error){
            // Displaying if there are any errors
                $('.result').html(error);           
        }
    });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The code above will echo 5 forms in this example, looking like this:
[image]

The form is submitted to **marked.php**, which will return/echo the result:

```
<?php 

$email_to_mark = $_POST['email_to_mark'];

$conn = new mysqli('dbserver', 'dbuser', 'dbpw', 'dbname');

$sql = "UPDATE table_name SET marked='1' WHERE email='$email_to_mark'";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo 'SUCCESS';
} else {
    echo 'ERROR';
}

?>
```

In general the form and the request work fine, but when I submit one of the forms, the result will appear in all class="result" divs on the page, looking like this:

[image]

When I change it from

```
<div class="result">
```

to

```
<div id="result">
```

it shows the result only in the first div, even if it's not below the form I submitted it from.

==========================

So what I need is the result to be shown only below the form I just submitted, like simulated here:

[image]

My attempt would be to create individual result divs with individual ids with the help of the table ids, like...

```
<div id="result_'.$row["id"].'">
```

...but since I am a JS novice, I don't know how to individually write into these divs.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh. I just added a very similar approach just a few seconds before you posted. But the JS part you suggested I don't really understand. I will try it though....

Answer (score 1):

**Try This,**
Changed your form id

```
<form action="marked.php" method="POST" id="form_'.$row["id"].'" class="marked_form">
```

replace result div class as id and add unique $row id or concate it

```
<div id="result_form_'.$row["id"].'">
    <!--echo result here-->
</div>
```

JS Changes

```
$(".marked_form").submit(function() {
        // Getting the form ID
        var  formID = $(this).attr('id');
        var formDetails = $('#'+formID);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'marked.php',
            data: formDetails.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {  
                // Inserting html into the result div
                $('#result_'+formID).html(data);//changes
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, text, error){
            // Displaying if there are any errors
                $('#result_'+formID).html(data);//changes       
        }
    });
```

just updated your result div id

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the corresponding id in js. For example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="result_'.$row["id"].'">
```

**JS**

```
 $('#result_' + formID).html(data);
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunatly. No result echo at all with this. Maybe some interferance with the fact that I am already using individual form ids? idk

Comment: Got it. Have to change either the form id to just the number, or include the whole form id name also into the result id name.

Answer (score 0):

Have Very simple techniques is there

Just use .next() function

$(this).next().html(data);

OR

$(formID).next().html(data);